# Place button in table? - react, coreui

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am using this table to show some data:

https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/table/

And showing the data works well.

I want there to be a remove button on each row of the table, if the button is pressed a onClick function is triggered that sends a remove request to the server with the index of the row that was clicked.

I am completely stuck and right now I am questioning if this is even possible? How do I solve this issue?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Hello, yes ! this is totally possible ! But where are you stuck ?

Generally speaking and without having too much details about where you are stuck, first you need a server up and running with some data inside (the data for your table). You then need to "connect" your app to this server by executing a query from your app to your server, this query is for your server to send you the data. Once this is done, you will have a better idea on how to implement a function from your app to request your server to delete one item from your data.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, kind of by accident after reading some threads. Anyway if anyone else is looking for a solution this is how I solved it:

The table takes two dicts, one for columns and one for the items in the table. I added a column called remove for where the buttons should go.

Then in the items table that is generated by going over the data from the server in a for loop, every row gets the button property like this:

```
remove: <CButton
          value={[dataField1, dataField2, dataField3]}
          onClick={handleRemove}>
          Remove
        </CButton>,
```

Then the handleRemove function looks like this:

```
 const handleRemove = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.value)
};
```

The handleRemove gets the data from the other cells in that row as the button when pressed. This information is then used by the server to remove the appropriate data